# Connect to kafka producer via websocket

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka

I am kind of new to kafka and I have a question is it possible to connect to a kafka producer using websocket. I want to send geolocation data from my Ios app to kafka producer using websocket.

Comment: Not directly, but yes you can forward any websocket data into a Kafka producer or consume Kafka and send via SSE or websocket

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you direct me to any documention or tutorial or resources to do so.

Comment: I don't have any. I'm just saying it should be possible. I have seen mentions of Akka HTTP to do something like this